# Python - English translator

Tags: python, localization, linguistics

What is the best way to approach writing a program in Python to translate English words and/or phrases into other languages?

Comment: Have a look at NLTK: http://www.nltk.org/

Answer (score 2):

[`AJAX Language API`](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/)

This is an incredibly difficult problem -- language is very very **very** complicated. Think about all the things you'd have to do -- parse the phrase, work out what the words mean, translate them. That's probably not idiomatic so you'll need special cases for different syntaxes. Many, many special cases. You'll need to work out the syntax of the foreign language if it differs from English -- "the big green ball" goes to "the ball big green" in Spanish, for instance.

Don't reinvent the wheel. Google provide an API to their translation service, which has undoubtedly had many many clever people thinking really quite hard about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into the Google Translate API. [Here](http://www.ohloh.net/p/googletranslate) is a library implemented specifically for this purpose in python.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to do this is to make a dictionary that matches one language's words to another language's words. However, this is extremely silly and would not take into account grammar at all and it would literally take a very long time to create a translator, especially if you plan to use it for multiple languages. If grammar is not important to you (for example, if you were creating your own language for a game or story that doesn't have grammar different from english) than you could get away with using dictionaries and simply having a function look for a requested match in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
# command : pip install mtranslate
from mtranslate import translate


>>> from mtranslate import translate
>>> translate("Tranalating to kannada language (my mother tongue) ", to_language = "kn")
'ಕನ್ನಡ ಭಾಷೆಗೆ ಅನುವಾದ (ನನ್ನ ಮಾತೃಭಾಷೆ)'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Goslate Package for that
its very easy to use
example

```
import goslate
print(goslate.Goslate().translate('hello world', 'ar'))
```

now first argument is text you want to translate and second argument is in which language you want to translate.

i hope you will find the answer usefull

Answer (score 0):

```
 # Please install Microsoft translate using >> pip install translate

 from translate import Translator

 class clsTranslate():

     def translateText(self, strString, strTolang):
         self.strString = strString
         self.strTolang = strTolang
         translator = Translator(to_lang=self.strTolang)
         translation = translator.translate(self.strString)
         return (str(translation))

 # Create a Class object and call the Translate function
 # Pass the language as a parameter to the function, de: German zh: Chinese etc

objTrans=clsTranslate() 

strTranslatedText= objTrans.translateText('Howare you', 'de')

print(strTranslatedText)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very very easy if you use deep-translator! Here's the source code(make sure to install deep-translator module):

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
import time
def start():
      while True:
                 def translate():
        line_to_translate = input('Which line/phrase/word you want to translate?\n')
        to_lang = input('In which language you want to translate it?\n')
        to_lang = to_lang.lower()
        translation = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target=to_lang).translate(text=line_to_translate)
        return translation

        time.sleep(1 sec)
        esc = (input("Enter 'q' to exit and 'r' to restart.\n"))
    while True:
        if esc.lower() in {'q', 'r'}:
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid Option!!')
            time.sleep(1)
            esc = (input("Enter 'q' to exit and 'r' to restart.\n"))
    if esc.lower() == 'q':
        return
    elif esc.lower() == 'r':
        pass


start()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# command : pip install mtranslate
from mtranslate import translate


>>> from mtranslate import translate
>>> translate("Tranalating to kannada language (my mother tongue) ", to_language = "kn")
'ಕನ್ನಡ ಭಾಷೆಗೆ ಅನುವಾದ (ನನ್ನ ಮಾತೃಭಾಷೆ)'
```